# Append port number to each item in comma separated list of IPs

Tags: bash

Need to append ports to lists of ips via bash script.

Sample input:

```
ip="100.100.10.10,200.200.10.10,100.201.10.10"
port="123"
```

Expected output:
`"100.100.10.10:123","200.200.10.10:123","100.201.10.10:123"`

I got it to: `"100.100.10.10","200.200.10.10","100.201.10.10"` using `hosts="\"${ip//,/\",\"}\""` but can't get the ":$port" appended to each ip. Would prefer to append it in the same hosts= script rather than adding more script conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just Bash you can replace the `,` by `":$port,"` and then add the port and the closing double-quote for the last IP address:

```sh
$ echo "\"${ip//,/:$port\",\"}:$port\""
"100.100.10.10:123","200.200.10.10:123","300.300.10.10:123"
```

Comment: updated answer to add double-quotes in the output

Comment: Please don't revert my edits to add quoting. We already get too many questions where someone copy/pastes sloppy code which seemed to work with trivial strings, and wonder why it doesn't also work with their less trivial strings. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: The revert was accidental. I submitted my edit after you edited because I haven't refreshed the page yet. Anyway, IP addresses doesn't contain white-spaces and the replace command as it is suggested in the answer doesn't allow white-spaces around the comma, so there's no actual need to wrap everything in quotes.

Comment: Thanks photonic.bean. Was beating my head on this.

Comment: Indeed, this code will seem flawless until you try it with different inputs, like I already alluded in my previous comment.