# Replacement inside var variable: add https:// and port to each IP on a list of somma separated IPs

Tags: bash

I have a variable with a list of IPs, and I want to replace each IP with `http://` at the beginning and `:8083` at the end.

My question is similar to this other question: [Append port number to each item in comma separated list of IPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378675/append-port-number-to-each-item-in-comma-separated-list-of-ips) but I don't want each IP to be surrounded by quotes each.

```
raw_ips="100.100.10.10,200.200.10.10,100.201.10.10"
address=magic-happens-here
```

The variable `address` should contain: `http://100.100.10.10:8083,http://200.200.10.10:8083,http://100.201.10.10:8083`. It's preferable that the `magic-happens-here` is some bash substitution trick similar to the one used on the linked-to question above (because of its brevity).

Comment: You have to do it in two steps. Add `:8083` just like in the linked question. Add `http://` similarly, but you put it *after* each comma instead of before, and an extra one at the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: If you understand how that solution worked, it should have been straightforward to extend it to this.

Comment: And if you don't, you should try to learn. Programming isn't done by copying solutions, you need to learn the underlying principles so you can do it yourself. You're a human being, not ChatGPT.

Comment: @Barmar Despite its similarities with sed I didn't really understand "how" exactly the solution worked with so many escapes and slashes because the linked-to answer didn't mention the name of the syntax. Now I found it's one of the so called bash substring replacement syntaxis. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how exactly you are going to use your list, but perhaps a more maintainable approach would be to convert your list into an array, then loop over the array and make the required transformation on each array element (which then is trivial).

Answer (score 1):

It was straightforward once I knew the syntax is called "substring replacement", in its flavour for regular patterns, whose syntax (for each match and not just the first one) is `${var//pattern/replacement}`. It can be done in one line with:

```
raw_ips="100.100.10.10,200.200.10.10,100.201.10.10"
address="http://${raw_ips//,/:8083,http://}:8083"
```

It replaces each `,` with `:8083,http://`, together with an initial `http://` and a final `:8083` to fill the head and the tail of the list.

Comment: in the general case, you need to test `raw_ips` is not empty otherwise your substitution can be incorrect

Comment: @jnhc Thank you for the tip, but in our case it won't be empty for sure.